# Ruby message error installing command-t plugin for MacVim in OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, vim, plugins, installation, macvim

I'm following this [video](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) tutorial for installing Commant-t on MacVim. At a point I'd have to perform the command `ruby extconf.rb` at the folder `~/.vim/ruby/command-t`. I'm getting the following error:

```
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ruby is missing the headers needed to build Command-T's backend. You have two solutions:

- Install [a proper Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).
- Use another fuzzy file navigation plugin that doesn't need Ruby *or* compilation:

  - [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) (needs Ruby but no building)
  - [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)
  - [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) (my favorite)
  - [others…](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php)