# Missing ruby.h header when installing Command-T

Tags: vim

I am attempting to install Command-T on OS X 10.8 and have followed the instructions on http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025, however when I try to build the Makefile I get the following error:

```
Command-T[master+]/ruby/command-t
 ❯ ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby.h... no
couldn't find ruby.h (required)
```

I am using system ruby, which is the one Vim was compiled (by myself) against. As you can see, Vim is compiled with ruby support:

```
Command-T[master+]/ruby/command-t
 ❯ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Command-T[master+]/ruby/command-t
 ❯ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jan 29 2013 10:09:48)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-785
Compiled by caleb@sirius.local
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
+mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm +mouse_sgr -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_urxvt +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L.    -L/usr/local/lib -o vim       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa     -framework Python   -lruby -lobjc
```

From Vim:

```
:ruby puts RUBY_VERSION
1.8.7
```

I've located the `ruby.h` file needed in /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/Headers/ruby.h and have tried both

```
export CPP_INCLUDE_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/Headers/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/Headers/
```

but neither of those make `have_header('ruby.h')` return true, and `ruby extconf.rb` continues to fail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having an issue with a plugin? Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I think this is more a specific error to my system than to the plugin, which is why I've shown so much background. Since I haven't gotten an answer here, I might try there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Though some alternatives are mentioned at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504579/ruby-message-error-installing-command-t-plugin-for-macvim-in-os-x-lion?rq=1), a few remarks might help.

First, the only c++ library path environment variable I'm familliar with is called CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and specific to the GNU Compiler Collection as mentioned [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).

Second the c++/c library path environment variables will not affect the ruby load path.
The searched paths can be displayed using

```
ruby -e 'puts $:'
```

And it can be supplemented via the [RUBYLIB](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/envvar.htm) environment variable. For example

```
RUBYLIB=/custom/path ruby -e 'puts $:'
```

should put /custom/path at the top of the load path list.

Which seemed to be the last thing you wanted to do.

Third and last, I doubt these things suffice to solve your actual problem: an incomplete ruby setup.